# How to import multiple databases dump to xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

How to import **multiple database** to xampp. I got databases dump, that file contain **many databases** data, when i try to import that dump file xampp phpmyadmin gives

> ## 1046 - No database selected

error, how to solve that issue please help me thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to do your dump again if possible.

How was your dump file created? From within phpMyAdmin, I suggest checking the box "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" when creating a backup, especially when exporting more than one database in a single file.

Aside from doing it again, if the export was done with phpMyAdmin, you can edit the .sql file in your favorite text editor and search for lines beginning with `-- Database:` -- those lines indicate the start of a new database in the export. Add a line there to create/use the new database, such as:

```
-- Database: `foo`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `foo`;
--
```

...

```
-- Database: `bar`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `bar` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `bar`;
```

If your file is large and you're ambitious, you could even script that edit with your favorite stream- or text- editor.

In the case that you wish to import to only one database, it's easy to enter that database in phpMyAdmin and click the Import tab from there, however that won't work for your case because you want to import to multiple databases, which is why you need to actually modify the file itself rather than do it directly from the GUI.